# Why is Maven uploading incorrectly snapshots to release repository?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm trying to use the maven-deploy-plugin to upload releases and snapshots into a Nexus repository. However I run across this error

```
[INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from nexus
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.jar
56K uploaded  (edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.jar)
[INFO] Uploading project information for edr-app 1.0.4-20120605.140242-20
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from nexus
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact info.afilias.edr:edr-app'
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from nexus
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot info.afilias.edr:edr-app:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from nexus
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.tar.gz
4286K uploaded  (edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.tar.gz)
[INFO] [deploy:deploy-file {execution: default}]
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4/edr-app-1.0.4.tar.gz
89530K uploaded  (edr-app-1.0.4.tar.gz)
[INFO] Uploading project information for edr-app 1.0.4
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from remote-repository
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact info.afilias.edr:edr-app'
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from remote-repository
[INFO] repository metadata for: 'snapshot info.afilias.edr:edr-app:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT' could not be found on repository: remote-repository, so will be created
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.tar.gz
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying attached artifact /home/mren/trunk2/target/edr-app-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz: Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.tar.gz. Return code is: 400
```

Here's my configuration in the pom.xml:

```xml
<project>
 ...
    <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <name>Releases</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>Snapshots</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
  ...
  <build>
   ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <file>target/edr-install-1.0.4-${revision}.tar.gz</file>
              <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
              <packaging>tar.gz</packaging>
              <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
              <groupId>groupId</groupId>
              <version>1.0.4-${revision}</version>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   ...
  </build>
...
</project>
```

And from my settings.xml file:

```xml
<settings>
  <server>
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <name>Releases</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>Snapshots</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

I'm sure this configuration worked at one point, but now it's spitting out an error. Not sure what is wrong.

And the nexus log tells me that it's trying to upload a snapshot into a release repository

```xml
jvm 1    | 2012-06-04 14:16:31 INFO  [tp1706427008-35] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository - Storing of item releases:/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120604.181534-1.tar.gz is forbidden by Maven Repository policy. Because releases is a RELEASE repository
jvm 1    | 2012-06-04 14:16:31 ERROR [tp1706427008-35] - org.sonatype.nexus.rest.ContentPlexusResource - Got exception during processing request "PUT http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120604.181534-1.tar.gz": Storing of item releases:/info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120604.181534-1.tar.gz is forbidden by Maven Repository policy. Because releases is a RELEASE repository
```

Comment: Have you checked the Nexus logfiles?

Comment: @wjans Yes I have, and it says that somehow a snapshot file is trying to be put into the release repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings.xml is incorrect. Please configure Maven to use [Nexus correctly following the book chapter.](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config.html) Specifically use the mirror settings and the url in there and not specific urls for repository and pluginRepository.

It interferes with your correct Maven pom and ends up trying to deploy a snapshot into a release repository, which is incorrect.

In addition it will be important that you use the correct goal/command. Do not use deploy-file goal directly or so.

Just run the command

`mvn clean deploy`

on the build.

And another clarification. Maven will deploy whatever is determined from the version. If it ends in -SNASPHOT is is a development version and be published to the snapshot repo (and will allow redeploys incrementing the version number) and if it does not it is considered a release and will deploy to the release repo. A project can not be a snapshot and a release at the same time. It is one or the other.

Do not mix the two concepts of release and snapshot!

And in terms of getting additional artifacts deployed I would either pull them out into a separate project/module if they are not associated or if they are look into the attach-artifact goal of the build helper plugin.

Comment: If I take out the deploy-file goal, only snapshots will be deployed and the desired file is left untouched.

Comment: what do you mean the desired file?

Comment: I mean, the file that I specified in the configuration of the deploy plugin isn't uploaded onto the repository when I take away the deploy-file goal

Comment: I see what's making the error, but I still don't know why it's trying to upload a snapshot into a release repository when I'm not actively telling it to do so.

Comment: I would seriously consider using the build helper plugin for your use case. It will do it just fine attaching the artifact and it will deploy to snapshot or release just like the main artifact.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are telling Maven to deploy a file that looks like a snapshot. Take a look at your deploy:deploy-file config. The ${revision} has the same format as a snapshot so Nexus nacks it:

target/edr-install-1.0.4-${revision}.tar.gz becomes: info/afilias/edr/edr-app/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/edr-app-1.0.4-20120605.140242-20.tar.gz

For reference the regex that Maven and Nexus use to decide what a snapshot is/is not is covered here:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/05/maven-code-how-to-detect-if-you-have-a-snapshot-version/

The other thing I would recommend is don't use deploy:deploy-file, instead use the buildhelper:attach to attach this tar.gz and then the file will be named appropriately, avoiding all of the hacking you did with the revision.

Comment: When I use the buildhelper plugin, the file edr-install-1.0.4-${revision}.tar.gz gets put into snapshots..

Comment: Had the same problem with a recent maven version 3.3.9, the release version was ended by a short commit, and it happened that the build that failed had a commit beginning consisting of numbers only, which matched the maven snapshot predicate. Adding an empty commit solved the issue, until proper solution is found.